# after_save callback: How to act only if user logged in or out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am writing a function to perform some actions when the user logs in or out. Using after_save callback in my model, this is how I do it now:

```
after_save :send_message


def send_message

  #how to send message based on log in/out?

end
```

The after_save gets called when user logs in/out or updates account, etc.

How can I trigger this send_message only when user logs in? And likewise, only when user logs out?

Comment: Are you using devise for authentication ?

Comment: I am not using devise for authentication

Comment: If you don't user Devise you should track when user sign in  and use an appropriate callback for it

Comment: how to do this? in my controller methods? is there a way to do it in my user model?

Answer (score 0):

In your model, add below code after the callback

```
skip_callback :create, :before, : send_message, if: :skip_some_callbacks
```

then in your controller, set skip_some_callbacks to false

```
def login
  ...
   user.skip_some_callbacks = false
end
```

Comment: my goal is add actions when the user logs in/out..does your solution help with that if i'm skipping callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

> callback in my **model**

You're looking in the wrong place - you need to perform this after the relevant **controller** methods have been invoked.

I know you're not using `Devise`; if you were, it has the *sessions* controller which `creates` and `destroys` sessions (IE when the user `logs in` and `logs out`).

You'd be able to create a [`before_action` or `after_action` callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for these methods:

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    after_action :setup, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def create
       # logs in -- creates session
    end

    def destroy
       # logs out -- destroys session
    end

    private

    def setup
       # do something after login/logout
    end
end
```